# C# Docked Ticker Bar for Windows 10

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to take up 15% of the top of the window and display messages for users (sales calls) and I do not want the user to be able to resize or close it.

If someone maximizes another application I do not want it to cover our ticker.

Comment: Are you building this application in WPF or WinForm?

Comment: I will use either one.  Do you have any input for which one I would have more success with?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example with WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="Ticker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Ticker"
    Topmost="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual" 
    Left="0" 
    Top="0">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Setting the height of 15% based on the height of the monitor:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Height = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.15);
        this.Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: this overlaps other windows as opposed to docking underneath.